# adding a php function into javascript

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

I have a file for a calendar made with javascript called calendar_db.js, in it there is this if statment:

```
        if (d_current.getDay() != 3 && d_current.getDay() != 6)
            a_class[a_class.length] = 'available';
```

it checks if the day is not the 3d or the 6th then. So my question is how to make a php mysql query to get those numbers (3 and 6) because I want to change them with mysql databse. 
What are your suggestions?

Thank you for your time and help.

Comment: Theres really no way of answering this without additional details of what your database table looks like.

Comment: it doesnt metter! all I want is to make a query inside this js file to change those 2 numbers. lets say we have a table called calendar, and in it we have id, first_number, second_number. and then in place of the number 3 it will be the first_number, and in the number 6 it will be second_number. so when I will change those numbers in the database the if statment will change automaticlly those values..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT:**

Read the javascript file by using fopen(), file_get_contents(), or CURL:

http://www.php-mysql-tutorial.com/wikis/php-tutorial/reading-a-remote-file-using-php.aspx

Use some kind of regex to parse the javascript file looking for the particular match of the line with your values. If your javascript file isn't going to change much, it might be easier to just count lines and characters and get the number at exactly some position. This assumes your numbers will always be single digits.

Is this what you're after?

Comment: yes I know what you want to say but those 2 values are inside an javascript file!

Comment: Glad to help. If this is the answer, might as well mark it as such instead of "can't be done" being the first thing future readers see...

Answer (score 4):

The short answer is:
You can't

However, you can use Ajax (Google it) to make calls to an external php file, which will process your request for you. Then, the php file can print out the result, which will send the information back to you.

Take a look here:
http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/default.asp

Answer (score 1):

You have to use [AJAX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29) to interact with the server via JavaScript.

Since the code to setup an AJAX request is a bit long and tedious, I'll show you how to do it with the [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) framework.

Basically, just make the server spit the two values out (imagine this being the output of **foo.php**):

```
12,19
```

Now, with AJAX you can read that output. There are two types of requests: `GET` and `POST`. If you're familiar with PHP, you can change this according to what your application uses:

```
var day1, day2;

$.get('foo.php', function(data) {
  var split = data.split(',');

  day1 = parseInt(split[0]);
  day2 = parseInt(split[1]);
});
```

Now `day1` and `day2` hold your two dates.